# Bokeh get_provider(STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA) wont work

Tags: python, bokeh, openstreetmap

I can not import STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA from Open Street Map in a Bokeh plot. There is no error displayed, the map will just not apper in the plot. (Things like line are diplayed)

When I use CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA instead of STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA everything works fine... Is there a known issue with importing STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA?

How I import:
`from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON_RETINA, STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA, get_provider`

How I use get_provier:
`tile_provider = get_provider(STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA)`

How I use it on my plot:

```
traj_osm = figure(y_range=(map_lon_m[0], map_lon_m[1]), x_range=(map_lat_m[0], map_lat_m[1]),
                            x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator",
                            plot_height = plot_h, plot_width = plot_w, title="Trajectory Map Catographical", tools=TOOLS)
traj_osm.add_tools(crosshair_maps_osm)
traj_osm.add_tile(tile_provider)
```

Comment: I just tried replacing the tile source in the [`tile_source.py`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.3/examples/plotting/file/tile_source.py) example with `STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA` and it worked exactly as expected. You need to provide a *complete, minimal script* so that people can actually take the code to run and investigate. Also: are there any error messages in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The skript where it is in is very large. I think I know whats the problem... it seems this provider is not suited for closeup looks on the map. In some places like munich the quality is on spot. But when I zoom in on smaller villages the map wont load and it remains blank. In my usecase i am probably to close.... As I said there are no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Right, the onus is upon the question asker to take a large script and pare it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) That means taking the time to make it self-contained and without any extra parts that aren't directly related or necessary to show the issue. You are asking people to spend their time, for free, to help you -- you need to meet them partway. In any case if the  STAMEN_TERRAIN_RETINA tiles do not exist everywhere, or do not exists in sufficient resolution, there's nothing to do besides use a different tile provider.

Comment: Yes I know. Therefore I just asked if there is some known issue with this provider. I did not intended to ask people try some code, because this seemed not necessary. My code example was just to show, that I use the libs in the right way (like in the tutorials. Anyway. Thank you for your answer. This is unfortunate.